# Align picture on webpage to the right of google maps

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align a picture to the right of my googlemaps on a webpage, Ive tried align="right", style = "text-align: right;" but it either puts the picture to the left of the googlemaps or puts it below it. i have tried putting them both inside  and tried creating separate    Any ideas? my code below

```
<div>
        <h4>Location</h4>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?
pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3286.997240714081!2d-84.00061768469592!3d34.52829788047906!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x885f6619cc5057df%3A0xb04a3ff6aa138ebf!2sUniversity+Heights+Apartments!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1497451987538" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="layout.jpg" style = "text-align: right;">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, I have created a fiddle using floats.  However, contrary to what you might think... I am using `float: left;`.  I have created a `<div>` to contain the `<iframe>` and a `<div>` to contain the `<img>`.  I set both the `<iframe>` and `<img>` to `width: 100%;` so they fill their respective containers.  This way, whatever width you set for the outer containers, they will fill them responsively.  Check out the fiddle:

[https://jsfiddle.net/fushniki/9cn3ptok/](https://jsfiddle.net/fushniki/9cn3ptok/http://)

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot! since I have a new stack overflow account it will not allow me to mark the answers useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the style `float:left` on your `div` tags.

```
<div style="float:left">
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3286.997240714081!2d-84.00061768469592!3d34.52829788047906!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x885f6619cc5057df%3A0xb04a3ff6aa138ebf!2sUniversity+Heights+Apartments!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1497451987538" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="layout.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using span , instead of div for 2nd div

```
    <span class="col-sm-3" style="float:left">
        <img src="layout.jpg" style = "text-align: right;">
    </span>
```